# cfmDamping: documentation please

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

What is cfmDamping and why was it added?
Does it replace

```
    dynamics damping="0.1" friction="0"
```

on all the atlas joints? Both kinds of damping seem to be applied to all body joints.
Does it lead to a more accurate simulation of pure viscous damping with a fixed value?
What is that viscous damping coefficient?

So everyone understands what I am talking about, here is the relevant code from
gazebo/physics/ode/ODEJoint.cc
When not at joint limit:

```
      if (this->cfmDampingState[i] != ODEJoint::DAMPING_ACTIVE)
      {
        // add additional constraint row by fake hitting joint limit
        // then, set erp and cfm to simulate viscous joint damping
        this->SetAttribute("stop_erp", i, 0.0);
        this->SetAttribute("stop_cfm", i, 1.0 / this->dampingCoefficient);
        this->SetAttribute("hi_stop", i, 0.0);
        this->SetAttribute("lo_stop", i, 0.0);
        this->SetAttribute("hi_stop", i, 0.0);
        this->cfmDampingState[i] = ODEJoint::DAMPING_ACTIVE;
      }
```

The old form of damping seems still operational in gazebo/physics/Joint.cc

```
  double dampingForce = -this->dampingCoefficient * this->GetVelocity(0);
  this->SetForce(0, dampingForce);
```

We need to understand cfmDamping to get our models of your model to be correct.

Thanks,
Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1860/cfmdamping:-documentation-please/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2013-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The damping method is selected in [SetDamping](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/3d057ec159d60aaff37dd03f4c2160853776d7d9/gazebo/physics/ode/ODEJoint.cc?at=default#cl-1038),

```
    if (this->useCFMDamping)
      this->applyDamping = physics::Joint::ConnectJointUpdate(
        boost::bind(&ODEJoint::CFMDamping, this));
    else
      this->applyDamping = physics::Joint::ConnectJointUpdate(
        boost::bind(&ODEJoint::ApplyDamping, this));
    this->dampingInitialized = true;
```

So only one of `CFMDamping` or `ApplyDamping` is called.

To answer your question regarding `cfmDamping` method, it is effectively moving the viscous damping force calculation into the constraint equation.  So the two methods should yield the same behavior if LCP is solved to infinite precision with infinitely small time steps.  The cfm damping approach has the benefits of solving for damping force implicitly, allowing infinitely large damping coefficients (converges to a fixed joint in the limit as damping coefficient goes to infinity).

The relationship between cfm, erp, spring stiffness (kp) and damping (kd) coefficients are layed out in the [ODE manual](http://www.ode.org/ode-latest-userguide.html#sec_3_8_2).  There's some more [forum discussion here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ode-users/toKqA9Z7L9k) for reference.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1